# Angular material backdrop placing [object Object] instead

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angular-material

Every time the md-select is opened, instead of the backdrop, I can see the text being added to the body. It looks like this:

[image: Screenshot]

Nothing special going through the code:

```
<md-select ng-model="project.filters.center" placeholder="{{ 'CENTER' | translate }}" ng-change="project.loadProjects()">
    <md-option ng-repeat="item in project.centers" ng-value="item.ID_CENTER">{{ item.NAME }}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

So I traced the problem all the way to the function showBackdrop, near line 19875 on angular-material.js, where it appends the backdrop.

```
if (options.hasBackdrop) {
  // Override duration to immediately show invisible backdrop
  options.backdrop = $mdUtil.createBackdrop(scope, "md-select-backdrop md-click-catcher");
  $animate.enter(options.backdrop, $document[0].body, null, {duration: 0});
}
```

So if I comment the $animate.enter line, the texts will stop appearing, as well the backdrop of course, but in this case I'm getting the object text instead of the backdrop anyway.

So is there a way to fix this? Why is this happening?
I can't just remove the backdrop because it's necessary to close the select when clicking outside, but that text is pushing my content downwards.

I'm using angular-material 1.1.3, latest version, I just pulled with bower.

Edit:

I kind of solved it now by replacing the $animate.enter function with a normal append

```
if (options.hasBackdrop) {
  // Override duration to immediately show invisible backdrop
  options.backdrop = $mdUtil.createBackdrop(scope, "md-select-backdrop md-click-catcher");
  //$animate.enter(options.backdrop, $document[0].body, null, {duration: 0});
  angular.element($document[0].body).append(options.backdrop);
}
```

But there has to be a way that doesn't involve modifying angular material itself.

Comment: I have run into a similar problem after updating angular material to 1.1.4. I have got to the same conclusion as you, the older version(1.1.1) of material used `options.parent` instead of `$document[0].body` and it was working fine. Funny thing is, the `select.js` file in the older version is using `$document[0].body` while the `angular-material.js` is using `options.parent`; the newer version is using `$document[0].body` in both files.
Where you able to find a solution to this issue?

Comment: So far the only solution I've found is the one I added in the edit, but recently we rebuilt the frontend so we don't have the same DOM anymore.
Funny thing: I hasn't happened since we did that, maybe it had something to do with a very specific elements tree which I won't be able to test anymore, or some quirk with some other plugin, as we are using far less plugins than before.

Comment: To follow up on this, I updated angular as well as angular-animate and angular-aria and the problem is gone. I believe it was the angular-animate update that solved the issue.